# How to update metadata on an existing object in s3 using javascript?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have tried using the copyObject method to update the metadata on my video. My video file ends up getting deleted and my metadata updated.
Why is my file being deleted?

I have attached some code snippets below:

I request the pre-signed url successfully

```js
let params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: filePath,
    Expires: this.expiration,
    CopySource: `${bucketName}/${filePath}/`,
    Metadata: req.body.metadata,
    MetadataDirective: 'REPLACE'
};      
      
      
 this.s3.getSignedUrl('copyObject', params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('err', err);
        res.status(400).send(err);
    } else {
        res.status(200).send(data);
    }
});
```

Then send a PUT request to the signed url successfully.

```js
let response: any = await this.$http({
    url: signedUrl,
    method: 'PUT'
});
```

But when I go to the s3 console, I see that my video file has been deleted and the metadata has been updated. What am I doing wrong? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I just figured it out....when I send the PUT request to my pre-signed url, I add an 'x-amz-copy-source' header and it works! My metadata is updated and my original file does not get overwritten and deleted. 
I used the documentation from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html).

So my PUT request now looks like

```js
let response: any = await this.$http({
    url: signedUrl,
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
        'x-amz-copy-source': `/${bucketName}/${key}` 
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem in your original code is the trailing `/` in `\`${bucketName}/${filePath}/\``